# Get data from local storage (SD card) of onvif camera

Tags: c#, camera, onvif

I'm developing a WPF application for `Onvif` Camera. By following the `Onvif SDK` I have successfully to connect the camera to get video stream and control ptz... 
Now I want to work with the `SD card`, the local storage on camera, but I'm have no information about that. 
Anybody can give me idea how to use `Onvif library` to connect to the `SD card` and get recorded data from that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From here: http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/recording.wsdl

You need to call: GetRecordingJobs

Find the recording job.

From here: http://www.onvif.org/ver10/replay.wsdl

You need to call: GetReplayUri

Comment: @ChirsWard: Yes. I've already read them from Onvif spec. So Do I have to implement SOAP web service for my app?. Whether it is available in Onvif library? If it is then I just add referrence and use it like a session dll that is Getprofile, GetProfileConfiguration...

Comment: I'm not sure what is available in the Onvif SDK as I have never used it. You will need to implement the recording and replay SOAP web services directly or indirectly in order to make the appropriate calls.

Comment: This will not download the recording. This will replay it in realtime, which means that if one is trying to get 1 hour of a recording it will take 1 hour to stream it and save the stream somewhere. The needed approach would be to download the footage, which should be possible via `http://www.onvif.org/ver10/recording/wsdl/ExportRecordedData`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this fits perfectly for your need, but I think it may help you. This code can be used to connect to an Onvif IP camera and to record the stream into MPEG4 format. By using this code, the recording files will be stored automatically on the computer.

```
namespace Basic_CameraViewer
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private VideoViewerWPF _videoViewerWpf;

        private BitmapSourceProvider _provider;

        private IIPCamera _ipCamera;

        private WebCamera _webCamera;

        private MediaConnector _connector;

        private MPEG4Recorder _recorder;

        private IVideoSender _videoSender;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _connector = new MediaConnector();

            _provider = new BitmapSourceProvider();

            SetVideoViewer();
        }

        private void SetVideoViewer()
        {
            _videoViewerWpf = new VideoViewerWPF
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                Background = Brushes.Black
            };
            CameraBox.Children.Add(_videoViewerWpf);

            _videoViewerWpf.SetImageProvider(_provider);
        }

        private void ConnectIPCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var host = HostTextBox.Text;
            var user = UserTextBox.Text;
            var pass = Password.Password;

            _ipCamera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera(host, user, pass);
            if (_ipCamera == null) return;
            _connector.Connect(_ipCamera.VideoChannel, _provider);

            _videoSender = _ipCamera.VideoChannel;
            _ipCamera.Start();
            _videoViewerWpf.Start();
        }

        private void DisconnectIPCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _videoViewerWpf.Stop();

            _ipCamera.Disconnect();
            _ipCamera.Dispose();

            _connector.Disconnect(_ipCamera.VideoChannel, _provider);
        }

        private void StartCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (_videoSender == null) return;
            var date = DateTime.Now.Year + "-" + DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + DateTime.Now.Day + "-" +
                        DateTime.Now.Hour + "-" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "-" + DateTime.Now.Second;

            var currentpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + date + ".mpeg4";

            _recorder = new MPEG4Recorder(currentpath);
            _recorder.MultiplexFinished += _recorder_MultiplexFinished;

            _connector.Connect(_videoSender, _recorder.VideoRecorder);
        }

        void _recorder_MultiplexFinished(object sender, Ozeki.VoIP.VoIPEventArgs<bool> e)
        {
            _recorder.MultiplexFinished -= _recorder_MultiplexFinished;
            _recorder.Dispose();
        }

        private void StopCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_videoSender == null) return;
            _connector.Disconnect(_videoSender, _recorder.VideoRecorder);
            _recorder.Multiplex();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here you can find a video explanation on how to implement video recording.](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_123-video-tutorial-on-how-to-record-video-in-c-onvif.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to copy video from the SD Card to a network storage using http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/recording.wsdl and the ExportRecordedData() method.